# How to get notification for updated version of the app?

Tags: android

I am working for check update version on the app and show alert every time when app start if there is update version of my app on google play store then alert should show but I am unable to do that .I searched lots of on google but nothing found. I know google play manage about update version but its my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the snippet you can check the **current google play store
>   version** with your **current built version** to send notification you
>   want...

```
public void checkUpdate(Context context)throws MalformedURLException,IOException,NameNotFoundException{
     URL updateURL = new URL("http://my.company.com/update");                
     URLConnection conn = updateURL.openConnection(); 
     InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
     BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
     ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
     int current = 0;
     while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
          baf.append((byte)current);
     }
     final String s = new String(baf.toByteArray());         
     int curVersion = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your.app.id", 0).versionCode;
     int newVersion = Integer.valueOf(s);

     /* Is a higher version than the current already out? */
     if (newVersion > curVersion) {
         //send notification to download your app here
     }
}
```